# If python had a preprocessor, deactivation of debug logging would be much less expensive. Any alternatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging, preprocessor

in my system I have placed a huge number of `log_debug(...)` function calls.

The `log_debug` function is implemented as:

```
def log_debug(*args):
    print("log:",*args)
```

As the system is in production, it's a good idea to deactivate the `log_debug`, for example, like this:

```
def log_debug(*args):
    pass # DEACTIVATED print("log:",*args)
```

Two problems are left:

1. the `log_debug` is still going to be called, with a small cost
2. all the strings that were created and sent to the `log_debug` are still being created, with a potentially much higher cost than point 1.

Point 2 is problematic in cases such as the following expensive string formation:

```
log_debug("foo: {}, bar: {}".format(foo,bar))
```

In some cases point 2 is way more expensive, such as the following:

```
log_debug("useful insights: {}".format(some_expensive_debug_data_retrieval()))
```

**Wishful thinking:** If this was C, `log_debug` could be defined as a pre-processor macro and completely deactivated in some header file, so that every argument in the `log_debug` is not even evaluated

Any ideas on how to solve this issue in an elegant way?

Comment: Use a general-purpose pre-processor as part of your production build/deploy step to convert the log_debug() statements to pass? I'd try hard to make sure that the source line numbers remain identical so that stack traces from production code match the lines numbers of the non-prod source code.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this with a global boolean, while not the prettiest, it is works.
It only has to execute `if DEBUG:` and not the expensive `log_debug()` after that. Example:

```
DEBUG = True

def log_debug(*args):
    print("log:",*args)

def function1(*args):
    if DEBUG: log_debug("foo: {}, bar: {}".format(foo,bar))
    #somecode
    pass

def function2(*args):
    if DEBUG: log_debug("useful insights: {}".format(some_expensive_debug_data_retrieval()))
    #somecode
    pass
```

Alternatively you can pass a commandline parameter and set the DEBUG variable.
I am sure there are more *pythonic* ways of implementing this. I was just going for simple.